# How to get Twist from rtabmap rgbd_odometry for use with move_base

Tags: slam, navigation, move-base, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using [rtabmap rgbd_odometry](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rgbd_odometry) to get odometry for my robot and now want to make use of [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) to get `cmd_vel` commands. When I receive the velocity commands though, I'll need to make sure my motor controller follows the command sent by move_base using a control loop which means I need information on the sensed Twist of the robot. But in the odometry message from rgbd_odometry, there is only position data (from what I've gathered, this is so because rtabmap does not require Twist to work).

Is there any option to turn on Twist calculation in rgbd_odometry or should I calculate this myself based on the position data (dx/dt, dy/dt and dtheta/dt)?

Also, doesn't move_base require Twist in the odometry message to properly calculate the `cmd_vel` ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223101/how-to-get-twist-from-rtabmap-rgbd_odometry-for-use-with-move_base/) by [boost](https://answers.ros.org/users/24400/boost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2015-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The twist values were added not so long ago (see this [commit](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/commit/97b7b0ccf4c426c79658252beba3e9e54b30cb04)). If you build the package from source, you should get the twist values in odometry messages. If you don't want to rebuild the package, you can set the twist values like in the referred commit (using the stamps for dt) with a second node.

Yes, move_base [uses twist values](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/d9e701e42b9d757b58893ca248d13faa8a3880da/base_local_planner/src/trajectory_planner_ros.cpp#L548-L551), though I think it may still work with null twist values (the [rtabmap's navigation example](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/StereoOutdoorNavigation) worked with stereo_odometry (same as rgbd_odometry) node and null twist values)

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2015-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [boost](https://answers.ros.org/users/24400/boost/) on 2015-12-26**:
Thanks!

```
odometry_->previousTransform().getTranslationAndEulerAngles(x,y,z,roll,pitch,yaw);
```

It looks like that line is getting just the **previous** position and angle. Shouldn't the velocity calcualtion be based on the **change** in position and angle?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2015-12-27**:
The "previousTransform" is the transformation between the previous pose and the current updated pose (see [here](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/blob/6c452137b23ebbcd151459a1dfff43b0f997cd82/corelib/src/Odometry.cpp#L269-L281)).

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2015-12-27**:
Note that it is the change in robot frame, not odometry frame, so that 'x' varies only with forward/backward motions. However, I'm not sure if the changes should be in odometry frame, but it seems to make more sense in robot frame.

**Comment by [boost](https://answers.ros.org/users/24400/boost/) on 2015-12-27**:
The "frame_id" I give rgbd_odometry is the robot's frame so /odom comes out in the robot's frame. I'll be going with a second node to compute the velocity based on the change in position to avoid recompile. Is it OK for me to copy the pose covariance for twist or better to leave them as 0?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-01-04**:
There is a discussion about the covariance in this [post](http://bit.ly/1PFY8FU). You may fix the covariance like in the [viso2](https://github.com/srv/viso2/blob/5f7403793faf255e40c1e0fee3f60f37655503d6/viso2_ros/src/stereo_odometer.cpp#L22-L43) package.